# Superglobals in Objective-C and iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, superglobals

I'm trying to add some sort of a superglobal in my app. It will only store a small integer, but I need it to be accessible from anywhere in my app.

I know you can use the delegate for this, but wouldn't it be easier if you could just set a superglobal in your application (of course it has to be alterable)?

So, what is the best way to create a superglobal in your iOS application?

*Oh, and I should probably mention I want my App Delegate to "own" the variable.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

define a global variable in some implementation (.m) file:

```
int superGlobal;
```

then you can access it in any other file declaring it there:

```
//SomeOtherFile.m;
extern int superGlobal;
```

Comment: Is it seriously that easy? Wow.

Comment: Yup, no super-anything needed. This is just a global variable.

Comment: @Emil, define the `typedef struct {} Type` in the .h, then the `extern Type blah;`

Answer (score 2):

What does superglobal mean in this context?

It's just C... you can easily define a variable in one file, and access it from all over the place (just use something like `extern int yourVariable;` in those files).

Comment: Superglobal as in a variable that can be altered from anywhere (provided the source is included in the .h-file) and read from anywhere. I'll try, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I actually ended up using `[(myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] myVariable]` instead.

I found that to be a bit more simple than having to import the delegate and class in every file.